# Error: could not find function "lmer"

Tags: r, lmer

I'm running RStudio Version 0.98.1062 on Mac OS X 10_9_5.
I loaded the Packages "lattice" and "nlme", and didn't get an error message. I read in some data and used some simple functions. But when I try to use lmer, I get the error: "could not find function "lmer"". Here is what I did:

```
> library("lattice", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library")
> library("nlme", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library")
> dat = read.table("StatsPrepDAT2005_2010.txt", T)
> table(dat$language, dat$data_time)
       2005 2010
  LW     37   69
  Wrlp   33   62
> dat.lmer = lmer(casevowela ~ language + data_time + (1|speaker) + (1|story), family= "binomial", data= dat)
Error: could not find function "lmer"
```

Answer (score 7):

`lmer` is provided by [`lme4`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html). You need to load it like so:

```
library(lme4)
```